# Using reference instead of isset()

Tags: php

In many cases we need to use isset() before accessing value of an array or variable received e.g. `$b = isset($a['key'])? $a['key'] : null;` otherwise error message shows.

But if using reference instead, check two examples below:

1. Normal case w/o isset(): error message shows as expected,

   ```
   <?php
   $a = []; 
   $b = $a['key']; 
   var_dump($b); 

   // Undefined index: key
   ```
2. Using reference as ***&$a***..: return NULL w/o error,

   ```
   <?php
   //$a = []; 
   $b = &$a['key']; 
   var_dump($b); 

   // NULL
   ```

The 2nd way is simple and convenient, but I'm curious how PHP works like this at an undefined variable?

Comment: The first one doesn't generate an error, just a notice. Trying to access an undefined variable always returns `null`, it's just that certain cases also produce a warning.

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: Your question is related to code compilation technique, which maintain high level language, like php, visual basic, translated to low level language like assembly, which some high level language will use the first appearance of variable as a variable declaration

Comment: Thank you, all, now I understand more. So will be that safe w/o side effect using like this way instead of isset()?

Comment: If you will modify `$b` - referenced value in array `$a` will be modified. Is it side effect for you? It depends on app logic. I think, construction with isset is more readable. You see code and it is clear that array may not contain 'key' and that `$b` will be null.